# Places in the cartesian plane

Tags: geometry

Okay, first of all, I will ask for an apology if this question is too basic for this site. I need help with this, and this is the site I like the most to get help.

We have two points: A (x1, y1) and B (x2, y2.

Now we want to find a point at which the distances to A and B are both the same. Which formula or procedure can help? We obviously know the coordinates of A and B, so I tried making some equations with two terms, but I got frustrated.

May you help me? Thank you.

Comment: *the distances to A and B are the same* — that's an equation for the unknown point(s).

Comment: The mid-point of $A$ and $B$ is one such point. Do you know how to find the mid-point of two points given their coordinates?

Comment: I should have wrote it in the ask, can't be the mid-point, must be a point that makes a triangle with the other two

Comment: @Katie: every point of perpendicular bisector except prohibited midpoint satisfies the conditions, then for unique solution you need to add more information

Answer (score 1):

Let $C = (x, y)$ be a point that is **equidistant** between A and B.  From the standard Pythagorean distance formula:

$$\sqrt{(x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2} = \sqrt{(x - x_2)^2 + (y - y_2)^2}$$
$$(x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2 = (x - x_2)^2 + (y - y_2)^2$$
$$x^2 - 2x_1x + x_1^2 + y^2 - 2y_1y + y_1^2 = x^2 - 2x_2x + x_2^2 + y^2 - 2y_2y + y_2^2$$
$$- 2x_1x + x_1^2 - 2y_1y + y_1^2 = - 2x_2x + x_2^2 - 2y_2y + y_2^2$$
$$- 2y_1y + 2y_2y + y_1^2 - y_2^2 = -2x_2x + 2x_1x + x_2^2 - x_1^2$$
$$2y(y_2 - y_1) + (y_1 - y_2)(y_1 + y_2) = 2x(x_1 - x_2) + (x_2 - x_1)(x_2 + x_1)$$
$$(y_2 - y_1)(2y - (y_1 + y_2)) = (x_2 - x_1)(-2x + (x_1 + x_2))$$
$$2y - (y_1 + y_2) = \frac{x_2 - x_1}{y_2 - y_1}(-2x + (x_1 + x_2))$$
$$2y - (y_1 + y_2) = \frac{x_1 - x_2}{y_2 - y_1}(2x - (x_1 + x_2))$$
$$y - \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2} = \frac{x_1 - x_2}{y_2 - y_1}(x - \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2})$$

Note that this is the point-slope form of a line that passes through the point $(\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2})$, the midpoint between A and B.